# neo4j shortest path works only when no nodes are specified

Tags: neo4j, cypher, shortest-path, py2neo

I am trying to obtain the node and edge ids for the shortest path between two nodes in my neo4j graph database.

If I do not specify which nodes I want, the code runs somehow and returns a path:

`import py2neo`

```
graph.run("MATCH (start:Point)-[:SOURCE_POINT]->(r:Road)-[:TARGET_POINT]->(end:Point) \
CALL apoc.algo.dijkstraWithDefaultWeight(start, end, 'Road', 'length', 10.0) \
YIELD path as path, weight as weight \
UNWIND nodes(path) as n \
RETURN DISTINCT { id : id(n), labels : labels(n), data: n} as node").to_table()
```

But when I run the same code and specify which nodes I want, it returns empty:

```
graph.run("MATCH (start:Point {id: '4984061949'})-[:SOURCE_POINT]->(r:Road)-[:TARGET_POINT]->(end:Point {id: '4984061963'}) \
...
```

If I simply try to match those node id's, it returns them ok - so I know they are in the db.

I'm thinking it could be because my 'cost' is a string. But I'm not sure how to cast it to float before it goes through the dijkstraWithDefaultWeight function.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have a couple of issues.

#### 1. MATCH clause is too restrictive

- The following `MATCH` clause would only succeed if there was a path between the specified `start` and `end` nodes consisting of *just one* `Road`:

  ```
  MATCH (start:Point {id: '4984061949'})-[:SOURCE_POINT]->(r:Road)-[:TARGET_POINT]->(end:Point {id: '4984061963'})
  ```

  If that `MATCH` clause fails, then your query would return nothing.
- The following `MATCH` clause would succeed if there was a path between *any pair* of `Point` nodes consisting of one `Road`:

  ```
  MATCH (start:Point)-[:SOURCE_POINT]->(r:Road)-[:TARGET_POINT]->(end:Point)
  ```

  If that `MATCH` clause succeeds, then, of course, the Dijkstra procedure will also succeed.
- Instead of either of the above, you should probably just use `MATCH` to get the two endpoints and let the Dijkstra algorithm do the job of finding the path:

  ```
  MATCH (start:Point {id: '4984061949'}), (end:Point {id: '4984061963'})
  ```

#### 2. Wrong procedure argument(s)

The third argument passed to [apoc.algo.dijkstraWithDefaultWeight](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#path-finding) is supposed to specify relationship types and directions, not node labels. Also, the last 2 arguments are supposed to be a relationship property and default relationship property value, respectively.

Comment: Ok thank you. How would I edit the MATCH clause to allow for any set of roads between node A and node B to succeed?

Comment: I just added a third bullet under #1.